# shellshock vulnerability and super user

Tags: bash, security

can shellshock vulnerability execute somehow commands with superuser permissions? 
And if yes, from where/how?

It is possible to be executed commands from cgi yes, but is it possible to get executed also as root? Can you give an example?

Comment: If you want examples, try your luck at [security.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. The mechanism of exploitation can work on multiple vectors as highlighted today. You just need something that eats a environment variable, goes on to run bash, and is running as root.

Will I give you an example? No.